# CDH4 - Mahout seq2sparse with custom analyzer

Tags: lucene, mahout, analyzer, cloudera-cdh

I'm newbie with Mahout and I try to code my own analyzer for seq2sparse. I use CDH4 with default versions: Mahout 0.7 and Lucene 3.6.

This is my analyzer code:

```
package com.analyzer;

import java.io.Reader;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.LengthFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.LowerCaseFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.PorterStemFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.StopFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

public class MyAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

    @Override
    public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        Version version = Version.LUCENE_36;
        TokenStream result = new StandardTokenizer(version, reader);
        result = new LowerCaseFilter(version, result);
        result = new LengthFilter(result, 3, 50);
        result = new StopFilter(version, result, StandardAnalyzer.STOP_WORDS_SET);
        result = new PorterStemFilter(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I built it in a JAR file and move to $MAHOUT_HOME/lib folder. My JAR is correctly added to classpath when I check with the following command:

```
$MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout classpath
```

But when I call the seq2sparse tool from Mahout with:

```
$MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout seq2sparse -i input_folder -o output_folder --minDF 2 --maxDFPercent 70 --norm 1 -a com.analyzer.MyAnalyzer
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.analyzer.MyAnalyzer
```

If I call with an analyzer from Lucene like org.apache.lucene.analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer, there's no error and job finished successfully.

How to add and use my own analyzer correctly?

Comment: Have you ever resolved this? If so, please provide us with the solution